# How to put a dot in Tikz Feynman vertices

Tags: tikz-feynman

I wrote this code

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{feynman}
        \vertex (a1) {\(\overline b\)};
        \vertex[right=1.5cm of a1] (a2);
        \vertex[right=1.5cm of a2] (a3);
        \vertex[right=2cm of a1] (aa);
        \vertex[right=2cm of aa] (a4) {\(\overline{s}\)};
        
        \vertex[below=1cm of a1] (b1) {\(s\)};
        \vertex[right=2cm of b1] (b2);
        \vertex[right=2cm of b2] (b3) {\(s\)};
        
        \vertex[above=1cm of a4] (d1) {\(c\)};
        \vertex[above=1cm of d1] (d2) {\(\overline{c}\)};
        
        \vertex (c1) at ($(a2)+(0.75,0.75)$);
        \vertex (c2) at ($(d1)+(-1.25,0.5)$);
        
        \vertex (e1) at ($(a2)+(-0.4, 0.4)$) {\(V^{*}_{qb} \)};
        \vertex (e2) at ($(a3)+(0.4, 0.4)$) {\(V^{\vphantom{0}}_{qs} \)};

        \diagram* {
        (a2) -- [fermion, very thick] (a1),
        (a4) -- [fermion, very thick] (a3),
        (b1) -- [fermion, very thick] (b3),
        (a2) -- [boson, bend right, very thick, edge label'=\(W^+\)](a3),
        (a3) -- [fermion, very thick,  out=90, in=0] (c1) -- [fermion, very thick,  out=-180, in=90, edge label=\({t,c,u}\)] (a2),
        (c1) -- [gluon, very thick] (c2),
        (c2) -- [fermion, very thick] (d1),
        (d2) -- [fermion, very thick] (c2),
        };
        
        \draw [decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=5pt}, thick] (b1.south west) -- (a1.north west) node [pos=0.5, left] {\(B^0_s\hspace{0.75ex}\)};
        \draw [decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=5pt}, thick] (a4.north east) -- (b3.south east) node [pos=0.5, right] {\(\hspace{0.75ex}\phi(1020)\)};
        \draw [decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=5pt}, thick] (d2.north east) -- (d1.south east) node [pos=0.5, right] {\(\hspace{0.75ex}J/\psi\)};

    \end{feynman}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

to produce the following diagram:

[image]

Can someone help me?

Thanks.

So far so good. Now I'd like to add a dot on some of the vertices (a2 and a3). I have read the package documentation (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.05437.pdf), but I was not able to use the "dot" command (page 15, section 3.2.3).

Answer (score 4):

In case somebody stumbles upon this question: just insert `{}` for the n otherwise

```tex
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{feynman}
    \vertex (a1) {\(\overline b\)};
    \vertex[right=1.5cm of a1, dot] (a2) {};
    \vertex[right=1.5cm of a2, dot] (a3) {};
    \vertex[right=2cm of a1] (aa);
    \vertex[right=2cm of aa] (a4) {\(\overline{s}\)};

    \vertex[below=1cm of a1] (b1) {\(s\)};
    \vertex[right=2cm of b1] (b2);
    \vertex[right=2cm of b2] (b3) {\(s\)};

    \vertex[above=1cm of a4] (d1) {\(c\)};
    \vertex[above=1cm of d1] (d2) {\(\overline{c}\)};

    \vertex (c1) at ($(a2)+(0.75,0.75)$);
    \vertex (c2) at ($(d1)+(-1.25,0.5)$);

    \vertex (e1) at ($(a2)+(-0.4, 0.4)$) {\(V^{*}_{qb} \)};
    \vertex (e2) at ($(a3)+(0.4, 0.4)$) {\(V^{\vphantom{0}}_{qs} \)};

    \diagram* {
      (a2) -- [fermion, very thick] (a1),
      (a4) -- [fermion, very thick] (a3),
      (b1) -- [fermion, very thick] (b3),
      (a2) -- [boson, bend right, very thick, edge label'=\(W^+\)](a3),
      (a3) -- [fermion, very thick,  out=90, in=0] (c1) -- [fermion, very thick,  out=-180, in=90, edge label=\({t,c,u}\)] (a2),
      (c1) -- [gluon, very thick] (c2),
      (c2) -- [fermion, very thick] (d1),
      (d2) -- [fermion, very thick] (c2),
    };

    \draw [decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=5pt}, thick] (b1.south west) -- (a1.north west) node [pos=0.5, left] {\(B^0_s\hspace{0.75ex}\)};
    \draw [decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=5pt}, thick] (a4.north east) -- (b3.south east) node [pos=0.5, right] {\(\hspace{0.75ex}\phi(1020)\)};
    \draw [decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=5pt}, thick] (d2.north east) -- (d1.south east) node [pos=0.5, right] {\(\hspace{0.75ex}J/\psi\)};
  \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked for me thank you very much!